# Why are core losses mechanical and not electrical in an AC power flow diagram?

Tags: power, motor, ac, power-electronics, generator

[image]

The power flow diagram of a generator (a) and a motor (b) are shown. But why are core losses mechanical losses?

Comment: There is one arrow for core losses and one for mechanical losses. Who claims that core losses are mechanical losses?

Comment: To rephrase my question, what I mean is that core losses appear before the conversion to electrical (a) and after the conversion to mechanical (b). Why don't core losses appear after the conversion to electrical power has occurred for instance?

Comment: Those arrows don't indicate any particular _order_; the losses all happen simultaneously. They're just staggered so that they don't overlap each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synchronous motor/generator has two power ports, a mechanical power port at the shaft and electrical power port at the motor/generator terminals.

Because mechanical losses and magnetic losses (core and stray losses) are (approximately) proportional to the motor’s **rotational speed**, they are often **taken together** and referred to as rotational losses. 
Rotational losses are mechanical in nature and are thus subtracted from the mechanical power.
**That's why the core and stray losses are shown before the conversion from the mechanical domain to the electrical domain.**

So, stray losses and core losses are not mechanical power losses, but they are subtracted from the mechanical input power (port). The mechanical power losses themselves are subtracted as well. This subtraction is shown by the down pointing wide arrows.

Literature:

- http://electricalacademia.com/synchronous-machines/synchronous-motor-generator-efficiency-losses/
- https://www.motioncontroltips.com/faq-what-are-rotational-losses-in-dc-motors/

Answer (score 1):

Core or iron losses are not mechanical.  They are mainly due to frequency and voltage, so they are constant.

Eddy currents (batteries set up by impurities in the iron) and hysteresis (heat created by reversing magnetic field) are the main iron losses.  Eddy currents are the main reason the core is made of laminated segments.

[image: Motor losses]

Comment: Laminated segments, or non-conductive ferrite or metal powder.

Comment: The non-obvious part is if it not operating at full load such as no load , the 5% losses are constant

Answer (score 0):

Core losses are resistive due to eddy currents that rise with f^2 and iron thickness, t^2 and and hysteresis losses due to nearing the L-10% saturation threshold.

Eddy current losses are the result of Faraday’s Law http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/farlaw.html  which states that, “

- Any change in the environment of a coil of wire will cause a voltage to be induced in the coil, regardless of how the magnetic change is produced.”
- Thus, when a motor core is rotated in a magnetic field, a voltage, or EMF, is induced in the coils. This induced EMF causes circulating currents to flow, referred to as eddy currents.
- The power loss caused by these currents is known as eddy current loss.
- Motors armature cores use many, thin pieces of iron (referred to as “laminations”), rather than a single piece, because the resistance of individual pieces is higher than the resistance of one, solid piece.
- This higher resistance (due to smaller area per piece) reduces eddy currents, and in turn, eddy current losses. The laminations are insulated from each other with a lacquer coating to prevent the eddy currents from “jumping” from one lamination to another.

Each layer also has capacitance (uF) but in series and burrs on the edges from cut Transformer shears can/may/will shunt laminations.